# Find a number 111...1 which is divisible by 2019

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find a number in the form of 111...1 (e.g. 111111) that is divisible by 2019. 
What I thought so far...

I know of Fermat's little theorem, which states following: $a^{p-1}\equiv 1$ for  $p \in \mathbb{P} \land a\in \mathbb{Z}$

111...1 (with n 1's) can be written as $\frac{10^n-1}{10-1}$. Unfortunately, 2019 is not a prime.

$\frac{10^n-1}{10-1} = 2019*k$ is also no solution to the problem since there are two variables.

Can anyone give me a hint how to find the solution or at least how to proof that the solution exists?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you write 2019 as a product of primes?

Comment: 3*673, does this matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), since $\gcd(10,3^3\cdot 673)=1$ then
$$10^{\varphi(3^3\cdot 673)}\equiv 1 \pmod{3^3\cdot 673}$$
or 
$$10^{2\cdot 9 \cdot 672}- 1 =3^3\cdot 673 \cdot k \iff
10^{2\cdot 9 \cdot 672}- 1 =9\cdot 2019 \cdot k \iff \\
\frac{10^{2\cdot 9 \cdot 672}- 1}{10-1} =2019 \cdot k$$

Comment: Nice.  $2\cdot672=1344$ works as well since we're only really concerned about mod 2019 and is probably the smallest solution.

Comment: @MatthewDaly indeed. I skipped these details since the question asks for "find a number" and "proof that the solution exists".

Answer (score 3):

Let $R_n=\frac{10^n-1}{10-1}$

We know by the pigeonhole principle that there must be positive integers $i<j$ such that $$R_i\equiv R_j\pmod{2019}$$  Choose such $i,j$.  Then $$R_{j-i}=\frac{R_j-R_i}{10^i}\equiv0\pmod{2019}$$ since $(10,2019)=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why does the pigeonhole principle say that? What if there is only one $r$ with $111...1 = k*2019+r$ ?
And how do you get the $10^i$?

Comment: @Quotenbanane There are only 2019 different remainders available, so eventually there has to be a repeat.  Also, if you subtract two different repunits, you are left with 1111...0000 where there are $j-i$ ones followed by $i$ zeroes.

Comment: Great explanation. Hope you have a nice day.

Comment: +1 for the proof, but this proves the existence of a repunit with the desired property, while the question asks us to *find* one.  Using this method, we have to find $R_i \pmod{2019}$ so it's no better than testing them one-by one.

Comment: @saulspatz True enough.  Only half a gold star for me.